# Why is the token consumption per request in Google Analytics Data API set to 1?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

The token consumption seems to have been 1 since around the beginning of this week.

I remember that previously the consumption was at least about 10.

I am wondering if there have been any changes or if there are preparing any changes.

Does anyone else have the same question?

The following is a partial request and response.

request

```
{
    "dateRanges": [
        {
            "endDate": "2023-03-30",
            "startDate": "2021-10-01"
        }
    ],
    "dimensions": [
        {
            "name": "date"
        },
        {
            "name": "pagePath"
        }
    ],
    "metrics": [
        {
            "name": "sessions"
        },
        {
            "name": "screenPageViews"
        }
    ],
    "returnPropertyQuota": true
}
```

rowCount(defined in response)

```
1114
```

quota(defined in response)

```
{
    "concurrentRequests": {
        "remaining": 10
    },
    "potentiallyThresholdedRequestsPerHour": {
        "remaining": 120
    },
    "serverErrorsPerProjectPerHour": {
        "remaining": 10
    },
    "tokensPerDay": {
        "consumed": 1,
        "remaining": 24975
    },
    "tokensPerHour": {
        "consumed": 1,
        "remaining": 4990
    },
    "tokensPerProjectPerHour": {
        "consumed": 1,
        "remaining": 1740
    }
}
```

Comment: I could not find a reason, but it appears to have been resolved on or about April 9, 2023.